# Kohana Auth Error

Tags: php, authentication, kohana

I have a Kohana 3.3.1 project and on localhost it worked great, but after moving it to server Auth module stopped working. I thought it was due to different PHP version (localhost - 5.4; server 5.3) but on localhost it didn't work either. After many tests i think the problem is the server database becouse it work fine on localhost but only on local DB. Can Anyone help?

Comment: Any error messages? Maybe deprecatet mysql extension warning?

Comment: No warnings or error messages. Server MySQL version  5.5.37, localhost 5.5.34

Comment: Have you checked kohana log as well as apache log?

Comment: „Check the phpinfo for where the PHP error log actually is (error_log variable) as it may not be where you think. Make sure error_reporting is set correctly and log_errors is turned on. Then hopefully you will find some more helpful error messages in the log!“